# How can I vectorize look-up table operations on massive 5-D data arrays?

Tags: python, bigdata, python-xarray

##### EDIT

In the end, this turned out to be the wrong approach to the question. I did something rather like what Michael recommends below, making the absolute match on one of the dimensions and then making the match to the second. I am unsure of whether to delete this or not, but I appreciate the help!

##### Original

I'm a longtime R programmer making a switch into the world of Python and Xarray and I've got a question.

Basically, I have a 3-column look-up table and two massive 5-D DataArrays with equal dimensions (68x144x5x3x713, to be exact). Values in `Array0` correspond to `LUT[0]` (in the example below, Frequency/Wavenumber); values in `Array1` correspond to values in `LUT[1]` (in the example below, temperature).

I would like to use these two 5-D DataArrays and the LUT to generate a totally new DataArray `Array2` with the same dimensions as `Array0` and `Array1` but with values drawn from `LUT[2]`. In the attached example, they should be Noise values drawn from the LUT.

I've built a small-scale example below

```
import xarray as xr
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Here's the lookup table
LUT = pd.DataFrame({'Frequency':pd.Series([715, 715, 715, 716, 716, 716, 717, 717, 717]),
                    'Temperature':pd.Series([250, 260, 270, 250, 260, 270, 250, 260, 270]),
                    'Noise':pd.Series([0.81, 0.82, 0.84, 0.84, 0.86, 0.88, 0.88, 0.92, 0.95])})

# Here are Array0 and Array1
np.random.seed(123)
size = 4
temperature = np.random.randint(0,3,size*size)*10 + 250
temperature.shape = (4,4)
FreqWN = np.random.randint(0,3,size*size) + 715
FreqWN.shape = (4,4)
lat = np.random.uniform(low=-90, high=90, size=size)
lon = np.random.uniform(low=-180, high=180, size=size)

TempArray = xr.DataArray(data=temperature, coords=[("lat",lat), ("lon",lon)])
WNArray = xr.DataArray(data=FreqWN, coords=[("lat",lat), ("lon",lon)])
```

So, from that basis, how can I vectorize the creation of a Noise DataArray with the same coords based on my LUT?

For simplicity, we can assume that all possible values of Array0 and Array1 are represented in the LUT. There may be edge cases later on but I want to start small.

Thanks, and sorry for any basic screwups - I know my way around data science at this point but not python.

####### EDIT - I have been asked to simplify the question #####

A simpler version of the same question would be - given a lookup table, that interpolates between Array0, the list of key-attribute pairs in the LUT, and a newly created Array2.

```
    LUT = pd.DataFrame({'Temperature':pd.Series([250, 260, 270]),
                    'Noise':pd.Series([0.88, 0.92, 0.95])})

# Here is Array0
np.random.seed(123)
size = 4
temperature = np.random.randint(0,3,size*size)*10 + 250
temperature.shape = (4,4)
lat = np.random.uniform(low=-90, high=90, size=size)
lon = np.random.uniform(low=-180, high=180, size=size)

TempArray = xr.DataArray(data=temperature, coords=[("lat",lat), ("lon",lon)])
```

I want to output a new `DataArray` called `NoiseArray` that is the same size as `TempArray` but uses the values as specified in the LUT. Does that make sense?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're asking, but it seems like you should just be able to select data using `.sel`. can you simplify your question to only use one array, and explain exactly how you want to reorganize your dataframe/array? you can always come back and do the same thing with the other array I think? unless I'm misunderstanding

Comment: Hi Michael - been a long time since Stanford ES! Hilarious and great to see you here. Sorry if the question isn't clear. I didn't think `.sel` would do the job because the output I need should be the same size as the input arrays, and using `LUT.sel` won't allow a comparison between the length-9 LUT columns and the 2x2 arrays. I've tried to make the question even simpler above, though.

Comment: whaaaat! I thought to myself "there's no way it's *that* Jared Brewer" :D ok let's see.... are you saying you want to reogranize LUT so it's the same shape as TempArray, but using the *values* of `Noise`, but selected from LUT where Temperature matches the values in `TempArray`, essentially treating Temperature as an index into Noise?

Comment: if so, can you do `LUT.set_index('Temperature').Noise.to_xarray().sel(temperature=TempArray)`?

Comment: It doesn't want to work - `KeyError: 'temperature is not a valid dimension or coordinate'`. I think I must have declared my TempArray wrongly somehow?

Comment: Oh sorry - temperature should be capitalized